# Javascript Canvas pixelformat

Tags: javascript, graphics, canvas

I have noticed that everyone working with the Canvas object multiply their way around the pixelbuffer by 4's (RGBA). I have worked a lot with native pixel coding (Delphi and C++) and recognize this as a normal 32bit RGBA (888-8 encoding). **My question is**: is there a way to detect the pixelformat of the browser? If you are running on a device supporting 16bit (565 encoding) or 24bit (888 encoding) it will be very slow if the browser has to downgrade the bitmaps for each redraw. Especially when alpha blending is involved.

Also (and this is secondary): Is it possible to create a pure 888 or 565 bitmap at all under javascript? Or what about an 8bit palette based bitmap? JS based games would benefit greatly only having to work with 8bit pixels in my view.

Comment: Notice that my question is: "is there a way to detect the pixelformat of the browser?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no seeming way to downgrade the pixels of the canvas, as that is what the imageData simply is as far as the specification itself is concerned.

You can of course make a javascript game using nothing but 8-bit PNGs, which would save space and load time, but not render time.

Comment: I guess the question could be re-formulated: If i run my code in a browser that supports 16-bit graphics only (mobile devices, although most support 32 these days), will the pixel data be in 565 format (word) or will it always be in it's present RGB-A format?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to specify what color space you want. Any manual hacks around this would only slow down the rendering further. In my experience, some browsers (Google Chrome) can render very complex games and still maintain a high frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are mixing two entities: image color space and surface color space.
5-6-5 is surface color space that has no concept of transparency by definition.
Image and the `<canvas>` are subjects of z-order rendering so must have alpha in one form or another.

So answer is 'no' because it is against requirements.

Comment: 565 is simply the encoding method, the "codec" if you like. I used these terms simply to underline the bit-range and storage medium of each pixel (which in this case is a 16 bit word). Decoding 15/16 bit pixels to RGB is very simple. The point was if there could be a speed boost on mobile devices in going after the raw pixel data in another way. But i actually did expect the browser to decode the pixel-data into an array of RGB values. As for Z-order rendering, that has to do with the HLI and not the datatypes.